# Google One-Tap Sign in popup doesn't show up after deployment

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I'm integrating Google's One-Tap Sign in https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/
I've registered new app in Google Api Console and get the client ID.
In terms of development - I did all the things listed in docs. On my localhost the one tap popup is displayed, and I see two POST requests with 200 status regarding that popup.
I've successfully decode it and got user's data.
However when I deployed the code - the one tap popup doesn't show up. And those two POST requests are missing from network.
I guess there's something wrong with credentials, but not sure. Does somebody has similar problems when working locally but not after deployment.
This One tap login is a fresh feature - and its difficult to find information on the web
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Some possible reasons are below:
1. One Tap can only be displayed in HTTPS domains.
2. In your OAuth client, you must registered the domains.

More details at: https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid

Comment: I'm running on https://<serverName>.<websiteName>.com
And in Authorized Domains section of my consent screen - when I put the address above  - it stores it as <websiteName>.com, omitting <serverName> at the beginning, not sure whether it makes some difference...

Comment: are you using a valid certificate for that server (eg. Lets Encrypt) or a self signed cert? Does Chrome accept that this site is secure?